# Why the configurable product price disappers in edit mode (Magento 2.4.6)

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4.6, configurable-price

When I try to edit a configurable product, the price is not displayed and the field to enter the price is disabled. Is it a BUG or a standard Magento feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **In Magento configurable product does not have a price. because it represents their child products.**

```
- main product -> No Price
    - Child 1 -> Yes price
    - Child 2 -> Yes price
    - Child n -> Yes price
```

Click here for more: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/catalog/products/types/product-create-configurable.html?lang=en